# Identity management in a mixed Linux/Windows environment

Tags: linux, active-directory, identity-management

At places like Google, where some users use Linux and others use Windows and even Mac, how are they managing IDAM?

For example

1. have a single directory service (probably highly customised)?
2. is it split into several controllers, say Linux, Mac and Windows?
3. or do they just use local users?

Comment: They use an existing protocol and services that all OSes have support for. Like Kerberos, Active Directory, even RADIUS, etc. The OS is not the limitation.

Comment: I get the impression that you think that this would be an insurmountable or highly complex problem, or in need of customisation, but it has been solved for a few decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Active Directory can be used out-of-the-box for macOS and certain enterprise ready Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu). There is no customization required.

macOS has a feature called [Directory Utility](https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/welcome/mac).

[Ubuntu's feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto) to support Active Directory.

The company I work for has a similar scenario than what I've described above and it works as expected.